# bash output always in console AND file

Tags: linux, bash, piping

On Linux, is there a way to both get the output of all commands in a bash and simultaneously store it to a file WITHOUT having to pipe anything. I know I could do something like

> ls -al | tee output.log

but I just want all output always to be stored in a log so I can look into it even after a few days.  I don't want to have to add the pipe with each command.

Comment: not sure this is solution, but you can use `your_app >> logfile.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want `script` command. When you run it, a new shell session is started and both input and output are recorded to a file specified.

Example:

```
script my_log.txt
# run your commands
exit
```

Record of your commands is stored in `my_log.txt`.

Comment: That works fine, thanks. Only thing is, that the output contains a lot of special chars like this: heESC[ESC[ESC[Kls -al. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: They are ansi escape sequences of colors in your output. Here is how you can get rid of them: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Comment: Or you can view the file with colors using `less -R`

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -al >> your_file.log 2>&1
```